# RavenDb and target machine actively refuses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.develop.com/Getting-started-with-RavenDB-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-app/#.UaWZckCnp7U) to use ravenDb as my persistance object.

On controller when I tried to save passed values I've got following error

```
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   public static IDocumentStore RavenDBDocumentStore { get; private set; }
   private static void CreateRavenDBDocumentStore()
   {
      RavenDBDocumentStore = new DocumentStore
      {     
         ConnectionStringName = "ravenDB"
      }.Initialize();
   }
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
      ...
      CreateRavenDBDocumentStore();
   }
}
```

I already tried with changing port number with `8081` or `8085` but either way error message is the same.

Here's my connection string section

```
 <connectionStrings>    
      <add name="DefaultConnection"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RavenMvc-20121125145005;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RavenMvc-20121125145005.mdf" />
         <add name="ravenDB"
         connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8085"/> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

After Raven server been started everything is fine.

Comment: have you turned off windows firewall?

Comment: @BlackICE just tried with firewall off. error is the same :(

Comment: Do you have any errors in the ravendb console window?

Comment: feel so stupid :) I actually not started raven server. Sorry!

Comment: happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that RavenDB server is running, and using the same port as your application does.

In the connection string you specify the port of the server to connect to, but you probably did not run the RavenDB server itself.

Comment: thanks for your feedback but I already tried with port 8081 and 8085, error remains

Comment: Actually, it means to opposite: RavenDB is not running on this port. Make sure to run the server on this port.